# Puppet: how to use ignore globbing on file resources

Tags: puppet

Consider the following puppet config snippet:

```
file { "/opt/app/${name}/traces" :
  ensure  => directory,
  owner   => 'appuser',
  group   => 'appuser',
  ignore  => [ '*.tra' ],
  backup  => false,
  recurse => false
}
```

The folder will contain "${name}..tra" files and I don't want puppet to take care of these files.

When calling strace or lsof against the puppet client, I can see it still tries to do something with these files (probably checksuming, according to the time spent on each file).

Thanks a lot,

Adam.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: Well, the question is, how do I tell puppet to ignore *.tra files from /path/to/folder".

Comment: I'm confused because you're trying to use "ignore" in conjunction with `recurse => false`?

Comment: Puppet agent is still analyzing these files (stuck because this .tra files are huge and confirmed by strace/lsof: puppet agent is reading them)

Comment: I have to agree with @AlexHarvey here that there seem to be false assumptions in the question and that I would have thought simultaneous use of `recurse` and `ignore` would fail the `validate` code block for the `file` type.

Comment: Yes, @AdamC. at the moment, your code is just creating a directory. And your "ignore" is being ignored because it has no meaning in the context of just creating one directory. Exactly what you're observing in lsof/strace or why we don't know. The exact steps to reproduce what you're seeing and what you're expecting would be required before we could help.